# Add additional property to tuple c# 7

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0

Had a search and can't find anything on this so I'm thinking it may not be possible at present.

Given the following two tuples

```
var a = (a: "1", b: 2);
var b = (c: "2", d: 0.1);
```

Is it possible for me to dynamically compose/merge these objects into one

```
var c = a + b;
```

Ideally the names of the properties are maintained so we can still do the following

```
var d = c.b + c.d;
```

I'm aware I could do the following but this won't work for what I want to achieve

```
var c = (first:a, second:b);
```

I'm looking for a general solution, i.e. I don't care how many properties are in each tuple.

Furthermore I'm aware that there could be issues such as what happens if there are two properties with the same name. In such a scenario I'm happy for the property to be overwritten or the name to be altered so it became a_1 for example.

Comment: You could probably have tuples of tuples, but why would you want to do that? If your models are getting that complex - make a real class to hold the values instead.

Comment: I want to write a fluent API that can forward pipe data whilst still maintain statically typed property names. I know I could use a dynamic but if this was possible It would lead to a very neat solution. For example, envision a fluent test runner that can pipe variables for reuse to the next steps, adding more data to the context would just be a matter of merging additional properties into the tuple.

Comment: @jps This isn't possible if you want to preserve the tuple member names.  Just concatenating two tuples to get a bigger tuple can be done with an extension method, but there's no way to preserve the names.  If you want statically-checked names you should really think about creating real types instead of relying on tuples.

Comment: Tuples do not implement the `+` operator.

If they did, the result of `(x, y) + (a, b)` would arguable be `(x + a, y + b)`, rather than `(x, y, a, b)`.

Answer (score 2):

From the way you describe your use case, you need to know both the name of the field and its value. C# 7's tuples aren't therefore going to be of help here:

1. Those tuples just map to `ValueTuple<,>`, `ValueTuple<,,>` etc, ie a tuple with two fields and a tuple with three are completely different types.
2. The field names are just compiler trickery. They exist as metadata for the compiler, but are not accessible at runtime, eg via reflection.

What you need are key/value pairs and sets of them that can be merged into new sets. Therefore the type that seems to best fit your needs would be `Dictionary<string,object>`.

Comment: I was tempted to suggest something like this too or perhaps an `ExpandoObject` but that feels even dirtier.